# Send OpenCV webcam image via TCP, best practices

Tags: python, c#, opencv, tcp

I want to send the images from my opencv python programm via TPC to a C# wpf application on the same machine. What would be a could way to send the bytes and render it in WPF?

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0,  cv.CAP_DSHOW)
ret, frame = cap.read()
# 1. encode as bmp?
image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.bmp', frame)[1].tobytes()  
# 2. encode as jpg?
image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()  
### pack and send
p = struct.pack(">{}B".format(len(image_bytes )), *image_bytes )
tcpconn.send(p)
```

I ask for performance reasons. Is a compression/decompression useful? I don't think so? Is chunking the data (e.g. image lines) a good idea?

I want to keep the overhead as minimal as possible. The c# code should be something like:

```
int l = stm.Read(buffer, 0, chunksize);
var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create( width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, buffer, width);
bitmap.Freeze();
image.Source  = bitamp;
```

Comment: With overhead, do you mean processing overhead or bandwidth overhead or latency? Best practice for video transport is video streaming, which includes an encoder and a decoder (e.g. H265) and can dramatically reduce the needed bandwidth, with a small image quality reduction and a strong processing overhead. If you don't want encoding you can calculate the necessary bandwidth by image-width x height x bits per pixel (typically 3 bytes) x frames-per-second (often 25). You should regard a protocol overhead. Typically you shouldnt expect more than 60-80% of your max (e.g. 800/s Mbit of 1 Gbit/s).

Comment: I do send it locally on the same machine so bandwith should not be a problem?

Comment: after `image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.bmp', frame)[1].tobytes()  ` you can use `cv2.imdecode` on the other side. `imencode` will create serialized data, which should be usable for data transmission. It should include a small image header which allows to create the image (stuff like resolution and bit depth). In C++ and probably in C# you will typically find methods to create images with given pixel data (without additonal copying of the pixels). I personally would rely on the transport mehods given by the backend and dont implement my own chunking, unless there is a known reason.

Comment: hmm I think I need chunking. tcp max packet size should be 64kb? an 600x400*8bit image is 240kb

Comment: Unless you want to display single image rows or have another good reason, I would try to use high level tcp transport functionalities that perform the content independent chunking itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "high level" can you give a link so that I can research?

Comment: for example a remote process calling SDK like Apache Thrift or a REST API SDK that supports large data transfer